# Filtering entries via a dropdown inside a Matrix Block

Tags: matrix, relations, plugin-sprig

I have Entries with a Matrix field called `events`. I have an Entries field and a Dropdown field inside those Matrix blocks (block type `event`). I'm currently filtering by entry using `andRelatedTo(['and', {targetElement: entry.id, field: 'events.entry'}])`.

I would also like to add the ability to filter via the dropdown, but I'm unsure of how I can target that dropdown:

```
{% set eventsQuery = craft.entries({
  section: 'events',
  events.event.dropdown: 'categoryOne'
}) %}

## I'm doing this with Sprig, so adding the relations this way
{% do eventsQuery.andRelatedTo(['and', {targetElement: entry.id, field: events.entry}]) %}
```

`events.event.dropdown: 'categoryOne'` is how it would work in my mind, but obviously is incorrect.

Can anyone show me how I could add the dropdown inside a Matrix block as a filter? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to do a `matrixBlocks` query first to get the IDs of all the relevant matrix blocks, then your `entries` query referencing those ids:

```twig
{% set blockIds = craft.matrixBlocks.field('events').type('event').dropdown('categoryOne').ids() %}
{% set eventsQuery = craft.entries.section('events').events(blockIds) %}
```

(Or here's the same thing if you really prefer the object syntax)...

```twig
{% set blockIds = craft.matrixBlocks({
    field: 'events',
    type: 'event',
    dropdown: 'categoryOne'
}).ids() %}
    
{% set eventsQuery = craft.entries({
    section: 'events',
    events: blockIds
}) %}
```

https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/matrix-blocks.html#querying-matrix-blocks

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm not sure if it'll work with the way I'm filtering stuff in Sprig, but I'll see how I go.

Comment: So I think this is my issue `{% set blockIds = craft.matrixBlocks.type('event').dropdown('categoryOne').ids()` is returning the same number of items no matter the category set. It doesn't seem to filter them that way.

Comment: Looks like you just need to specify the Matrix field too: `{% set blockIds = craft.matrixBlocks.field('events').type('event').dropdown('categoryOne').ids() %}` Bingo! Thanks!